# How I can point src image tag to render image file from my local directory using json field in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, path, src

I have very specific case on how I can render images using `src`. The case is that I have flask app returning json objects

```
{
    "filepath": "0.jpg",
    "group": "terminator",
    "id": "0",
    "isClicked": false,
    "title": "image_0"
},
{
    "filepath": "1.jpg",
    "group": "terminator",
    "id": "1",
    "isClicked": false,
    "title": "image_1"
}
```

and in the file directory I have images folder outside the react app

[image]

The question is how I can set the img src to render the images of  the `images` folder, I have tried

```
        <ul>
          {Object.values(items).map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <li>
                {item.group} {item.title}
              </li>
              <img src={item.filepath} alt={item.title}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

it render the group and title but not the img, then I tried to set a relative path like this
`<img src={`../../images/${item.filepath}`} />`
and it didn't work. please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

oh, I just did this

```
<img src={require(`../../images/${item.filepath}`).default} />
```

and it worked